# How to add time through methods, addHours() in Java

Tags: java, constructor, enumeration

I am trying to get this Airplane project to work and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to add up the time in the "public void addHours() ", or if I even did the prior correct! Any help would be fantastic!

Question to be answered:

> Create a Time class. This class will represent a point in time, such
>   as a departure time. It should contain 2 constructors, 2 instance
>   variables (hour and minute), and 10 methods (see below). All methods
>   but toString should be in terms of the 24 hour format. default
>   constructor: Creates a Time object for 12:00AM. overloaded
>   constructor: Creates a Time object at a specific hour and minute.
>   getHour(): Returns an integer representing the hour of the Time
>   object. getMinute(): Returns an integer representing the minute of the
>   Time object. **addHours(...): Updates the object by moving it forward a
>   number of hours.** addMinute(...): Updates the object by moving it
>   forward a number of minutes. (Hint: Be careful that you don't allow
>   minutes to be more than 59.) addTime(...): Updates the object by
>   moving it forward by the hour and minute from another Time object.
>   getCopy(...): Returns a new Time object that has the same hour and
>   minute of the existing Time object. isEarlierThan(...): Returns true
>   if this Time object is earlier than another Time object.
>   isSameTime(...): Returns true if this Time object is the same as
>   another Time object. isLaterThan(...): Returns true if this Time
>   object is later than another Time object. toString(): Returns a string
>   representing the Time object. Uses 12 hour AM/PM format and pads
>   minutes to be two digits. See the sample output for an example.

This is my Time class so far:

```
public class Time {
    public static int hour;
    public static int minute;

    public Time() {
    }
    public Time(int h, int m) {
        h = hour;
        m = minute;
    }
    public int getHour() {
        return hour;
    }
    public int getMinute() {
        return minute;
    }
    public void addHours(int h) {
        h = h + hour;
    }
    public void addMinutes(int m) {
        //Minute should not allow past 59 minutes.
        if (m <= 59)
        m = m + minute;
    }
    public void addTime(Time other) { 
    }
    public Time getCopy() {
        //need to fix return statement
        return null;
    }
    public boolean isEarlierThan(Time other) {
        return (Boolean) null;
        //need to fix return statement.
    }
    public boolean isSameTime(Time other) {
        return (Boolean) null;
        //need to fix return statement.
    }
    public boolean isLaterTHan(Time other) {
        return (Boolean) null;
        //need to fix return statement.
    }
    public String formatDigits(int i) {
        return null;
        //need to fix return statement.
    }
    public String toString() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Below is the Driver:

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Please note that these tests are not comprehensive.
        //testAirline();
        //testAirport();
        //testPlane();
        //testTime();
        //testFlight();
    }

    public static void testAirline() {
        System.out.println("==testAirline()==");
        /*
        //Test 1: create enum variables
        Airline a1 = Airline.American;
        Airline a2 = Airline.United;
        Airline a3 = Airline.Delta;
        Airline a4 = Airline.United;

        //Test 2: display and compare variables
        System.out.println("a1: " + a1);
        System.out.println("a2 == a3: " + (a1 == a2));
        System.out.println("a2 == a4: " + (a2 == a4));
        */
    }

    public static void testAirport() {
        System.out.println("==testAirport()==");

        /*
        //Test 1: create enum variables
        Airport a1 = Airport.PHX;
        Airport a2 = Airport.LAX;
        Airport a3 = Airport.SFO;
        Airport a4 = Airport.NRT;
        Airport a5 = Airport.SIN;

        //Test 2: display and compare variables
        System.out.println("a1: " + a1);
        System.out.println("a2 == a3: " + (a1 == a2));
        System.out.println("a2 == a4: " + (a2 == a4));
        System.out.println("a1: " + Airport.getAirportCity(a1));
        System.out.println("a3: " + Airport.getAirportCity(a3));
        System.out.println("a5: " + Airport.getAirportCity(a5));
        */
    }

    public static void testPlane() {
        System.out.println("==testPlane()==");
        /*

        //Test 1: create plane objects
        Plane p1 = new Plane(Airline.Delta, "Boeing 717");
        Plane p2 = new Plane(Airline.United, "Airbus A321");

        //Test 2: display plane information.
        System.out.println(p1.getAirline());
        System.out.println(p1.getModel());
        System.out.println(p1);
        System.out.println(p2);
        */
    }

    public static void testTime() {
        System.out.println("==testTime()==");

        /*
        //Test 1: use default constructor.
        Time t1 = new Time();

        //Test 2: use overloaded constructor.
        Time t2 = new Time(9, 0);
        Time t3 = new Time(1, 15);

        //Test 3: use clone operation.
        Time t4 = t3.getCopy();

        //Test 4: run toString on AM times.
        System.out.println(new Time(0, 5));
        System.out.println(new Time(1, 15));
        System.out.println(new Time(2, 45));
        System.out.println(new Time(10, 5));
        System.out.println(new Time(11, 15));
        //Test 5: run toString on PM times.
        System.out.println(new Time(12, 45));
        System.out.println(new Time(13, 5));
        System.out.println(new Time(22, 15));
        System.out.println(new Time(23, 45));

        //Test 6: run toString on object from default constructor.
        System.out.println("t1: " + t1);

        //Test 7: testing addTime operation
        System.out.println("t2: " + t2);
        t2.addTime(t3);
        System.out.println("t2: " + t2);
        //Test 8: testing addMinutes operation
        t2.addMinutes(181);
        System.out.println("t2: " + t2);
        //Test 9: testing8 addHours operation
        t2.addHours(2);
        System.out.println("t2: " + t2);

        //Test 10: testing cloned copy.
        t4.addHours(1);
        System.out.println("t3: " + t3);//original
        System.out.println("t4: " + t4);//clone

        //Test 11: testing isEarlierThan.
        System.out.println("t3 < t4: " + t3.isEarlierThan(t4));
        System.out.println("t4 < t3: " + t4.isEarlierThan(t3));
        System.out.println("t2 < t4: " + t2.isEarlierThan(t4));
        System.out.println("t4 < t2: " + t4.isEarlierThan(t2));
        System.out.println("t2 < t2: " + t2.isEarlierThan(t2));

        //Test 12: testing isLaterThan.
        System.out.println("t2 > t4: " + t2.isLaterThan(t4));
        System.out.println("t4 > t2: " + t4.isLaterThan(t2));
        System.out.println("t4 > t4: " + t4.isLaterThan(t4));

        //Test 13: testing isSameTime.
        System.out.println("t2 = t4: " + t2.isSameTime(t4));
        System.out.println("t4 = t4: " + t4.isSameTime(t4));
        System.out.println("t4 = 2:15AM: " + t4.isSameTime(new Time(2, 15)));
        */
    }

    public static void testFlight() {
        System.out.println("==testFlight()==");
        /*
        //Test 1: create flights using different settings
        Flight f1 = new Flight(new Plane(Airline.American, "Airbus A321"), 
                               "495", 
                               79,
                               new Time(11,5), 100,
                               Airport.PHX, Airport.LAX);

        Flight f2 = new Flight(new Plane(Airline.Delta, "Boeing 717"),
                               "1063",
                               79,
                               new Time(7, 10),
                               95,
                               Airport.PHX,
                               Airport.LAX);

        Flight f3 = new Flight(new Plane(Airline.American, "Airbus A321"),
                               "400",
                               44,
                               new Time(21, 25),
                               127,
                               Airport.PHX,
                               Airport.SFO);

        Flight f4 = new Flight(new Plane(Airline.United, "Boeing 787"),
                               "400",
                               525,
                               new Time(10, 50),
                               715,
                               Airport.LAX,
                               Airport.NRT);

        Flight f5 = new Flight(new Plane(Airline.United, "Boeing 737"),
                               "414",
                               59,
                               new Time(6, 50),
                               85,
                               Airport.LAX,
                               Airport.SFO);


        System.out.println(f1.toDetailedString()); 
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(f1.toOverviewString());

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println(f5.toDetailedString()); 
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(f5.toOverviewString());
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be assigning to `hour` and not `h`. You have a similar problem throughout your class. Also, your fields should not be `static`.

Comment: I have updated the 'hour = h + hour;' and minute as well. My question being how do I update the addTime method. I have tried like a million different things and have gotten like a million different errors. I am just lost.

Comment: show us one of the million different things by posting it in your question

Comment: The main thing I am trying to figure out is how to update "Time Other" so I can use it in AddTime and the boolean fields to return the proper values.

Comment: I realize this is homework assignment for practice, but, for the record, in real work you should use the java.time classes such as [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) rather than roll-your-own date-time handling classes.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
hour += h;
```

instead of

```
h = h + hour;
```

Also in the function `addMinutes` use the following:

```
minute += m;
if(minute > 59){
    hour += minute/60;
    minute = minute%60;
}
```

Also declaring `hour` and `minute` as `static` would result to modification of these variables will share the same value across all instances and any modification in one instance would result in modification of all other instances.

**After Your Comment**

As far as the current code is concerned, since you have decalred `hour` and `minute` as `static` the `addTime` method would only double the current time.

Since you want to convert the `hour` and `minute` to instance variable, I think that the next process of `addTime` is very simple. You have stated that you have tried a million things, yet are unable to post even a single thing. So, I would consider that you have not tried and are simply asking us to give you the solution. Still, I would provide you with the solution:

```
public void addTime(Time other){
    addHours(other.getHour());
    addMinutes(other.getMinute());
}
```

Other than these there is another problem of AM/PM in your solution. Also you have not taken care of the condition when any amount of minutes are added to a time that is 11:59 PM.

If you want to get solution for other methods, please attempt yourself first. Then if you face any problem then post the question with the relevant code.

Comment: How would I apply this to the addTime method? The original constructor Time, has an object set to it for 12:00AM. How would I update the Other object to the addMinutes method.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan firstly do you want `minute` and `hour` variables to be class variables or instance variables. Since you have used them as class variables, there is no utility of the method `addTime` method as it would simply double the existing time whatever you do.

Comment: I removed static from Minute and Hour.
addHours(...): Updates the object by moving it forward a number of hours.

addMinute(...): Updates the object by moving it forward a number of minutes. (Hint: Be careful that you don't allow minutes to be more than 59.)
^^ The above is accomplished.
addTime(...): Updates the object by moving it forward by the hour and minute from another Time object.
getCopy(...): Returns a new Time object that has the same hour and minute of the existing Time object.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan I have posted the solution, for `addTime` there are other problems in your problem which you have not as yet considered. Kindly try to solve them your self.

Answer (score -1):

Modify your addHours and addMinutes method

```
public void addHours(int h) {
    h = h + hour;
}
public void addMinutes(int m) {
    //Minute should not allow past 59 minutes.
    if (m <= 59)
    m = m + minute;
}
```

to this

```
public void addHours(int h) {
    hour += h;
}
public void addMinutes(int m) {
    minute += m;
   if(minute > 59){
       hour += minute/60;
       minute = minute%60;
   }
}
```

Explanation : Whenever you add min, it might change your hour also. and you have new hour and minutes.

Eg. 10 minutes is added to 55 minutes will increase hour by one and new minute is 5

Comment: So how would I include these with the addTime method?